# Choosing positive reals $\alpha_i$ for $a_iX_i \sim N(0, a_i^2)$ such that $a_iX_i \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> Suppose we have a decreasing sequence $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. That is
>
> $$\mathbb{R}^{+} \ni \alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq \cdots > 0.$$
>
> Further, let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} \sim N(0,1)$, and define $Y_i := \alpha_iX_i \sim N(0, \alpha_i^2)$. What conditions does the sequence $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ need such that $Y_i \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0$?

**What I have:**

**1.** For each $i$ we want to show that for every $\epsilon_i > 0$ there exists some constant $c_i$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(|a_iX_i| > c_i) = \mathbb{P}(|Y_i| > c_i) \leq \epsilon_i. \tag{$\star$}$$

So, I need to find some systematic way of choosing $\epsilon_i$ and $\alpha_i$ such that for any $\delta > 0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(|Y_i| > \delta) \to 0$. I've been focusing on a method to incorporate the variances $\alpha_i^2$, which seems important in choosing $c_i$, i.e. the larger the variances, the flatter the pdf of $Y_i$, the larger $c_i$ needs to be to satisfy $(\star)$. **I'm not seeing how to easily do this?**

**2.** Once we have (1) satisfied, then we can apply the Borel-Cantelli Lemma to show that for all $\epsilon_i > 0$ we have

$$\sum_{i \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|Y_i| > \epsilon_i) < \infty \quad\Rightarrow\quad Y_i \stackrel{a.s.}{\to} 0,$$

which in turn answers the question of how to choose sufficient $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(|\alpha_iX_i| >\epsilon)= P(|X_i| >\frac {\epsilon} {\alpha_y})\leq \frac {EX_i^{2}} {(\frac {\epsilon} {\alpha_y})^{2}}=\alpha_i^{2}/\epsilon^{2}$. So $\sum \alpha_i^{2} <\infty$ is a sufficient condition (by Borel Cantelli Lemma).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ \mathbb{P}[\lvert \alpha_i X_i \rvert > c_i] = \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_i \rvert > \frac{c_i}{\alpha_i}] \leq \frac{\alpha_i}{c_i} \mathbb{E}[\lvert X_i \rvert ] = \frac{\alpha_i}{c_i} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

by Markovs inequality. For the last inequality I used that the absolute value of a normal distribution follows the [half - normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).

Comment: You a get a better conclusion by using the second moment instead of the first absolute moment. Note  that $\sum |\alpha_i| <\infty$ implies $\sum \alpha_i^{2} <\infty$ so $\sum |\alpha_i| <\infty$ is a stronger assumption.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are right. But since I didn't claim to answer the question I think it is alright to suggest the use of Markovs inequality, since once this idea is establishedthe OP might try to use Chebyshevs inequality too.

Comment: Sure. My intension was not to critisize your answer. I thought my comment could benefit some others.